# do something based on the type of variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function in VBA that usually returns an array. If there is nothing to return it returns an empty variable (`b = empty`).
I have some code to loop though the array but I get an error if the variable is not an array. How can I make an if statement that doesn't cause its own error. I have tried

```
if not b = empty then
'do the loop
end if
```

but this gives an error when b is an array
Similarly I get error for `b = null`, `b = nothing`, `b(1,1) = ""` etc.

What is the best way to check this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To test if a variable is empty, use the [IsEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264227.aspx) function.

```
If IsEmpty(b) Then
    Debug.Print "b is Empty"
End If
```

To test if a variable is an array, use the [VarType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278470.aspx) function.

```
If VarType(b) And vbArray Then
    Debug.Print "b is an array"
End If
```

Comment: There is also the `IsArray()` function, which can be used instead of the second example.